# Syntax error loading content dynamically in html page with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, innerhtml

I am trying to load some content dynamically in my HTML div. If I try to do this, I get an error: Syntax error HOME. (this is the content that should be visible within the div).

**HTML:**
Navigation bar:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="replaceContent('home.html')">Home</a></li>
```

Div to be filled:

```
<div id="pagepanel"></div>
```

**home.html**

```
HOME.
```

**Javascript:**

```
function replaceContent(newDiv) {
    var xmlHttp = createXMLHttp();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){replace(xmlHttp);}
    xmlHttp.open("GET", newDiv, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function replace(xmlHttp) {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("pagepanel").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
    alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
}

function createXMLHttp() {
    var xmlHttp;
    if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        alert("Please upgrade your browser! Your browser does not support AJAX!");
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

Comment: wat does this 'onLoad="replaceDiv('home.html')' do?

Comment: Not a thing. I did not rename the function call in that piece of html, sorry.

Comment: I'm not quite sure... but shouldn't be there at least a <html> (or other) Tag in your home.html?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, because the xmlHttp object's open function should open any file (e.g. txt, html, js). The only thing I am trying to accomplish here is to set the content of a file inside a div. Including a html tag would mutilate the div's inner structure because there will be a html tag within a div tag. (Correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Why you don't use jquery? It's kind of requirement?

Comment: what does the alert statement tell you?
i cannot see anything wrong in the ajax calls, though using jquery would make all this easier, if you are willing to go that way

Comment: The alert statement tells me: HOME. (the content of the home.html page). I do not use JQuery because I am not fond of using JQuery for such a small task. I do not need any other actions to be taken care of so in my opinion JQuery will be quite a bit overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred due to the lack of a semi-colon.

```
onclick="replaceContent('home.html')";>Home</a></li>
```